# Which is the most pythonic way to check if the current method has been executed in a specific method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python 3 and I am trying to check if the current method has been called from a specific method. This one has not to be necessarily the parent call, only one of the ancestors.

> Example:
>
> I need to know if the method **F** is called from the method
> **C**. The method **A** calls **B**, **B** calls **C**, **C** calls **D**, **D** calls **E**, **E** calls **F**. So the ancestor methods of **F** are **[A, B, C, D, E]**. Since **C** is in this list, my
> method returns `True`, otherwise returns `False`.

I have two solutions (I will replace the method names with parameters):

First one, which I think is faster:

```
for frame in inspect.stack():
    if frame.function == 'C':
        return True
```

Second one:

```
methods = [frame.function for frame in inspect.stack()]
if 'C' in methods:
    return True
```

Is the first solution better? Any suggestion to improve it? Is this already made in any library?

Comment: `return next((True for frame in inspect.stack() if frame.function == 'C'), False)` -- like the 1st solution, this one short-circuits

Comment: why do you want to do this though? can you give more context?

Comment: @VPfB Not if you specify a default value (like i did of `False`)

Comment: @Chris_Rands I am developing in Odoo ERP and I need to know if one method which creates an account move comes from one method which closes the POS. I mean, I need to perform an action if an account move has been generated by the point of sale, and follow the standard behavior if not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd go with solution c, `any`

```
any(f.function == 'C' for f in inspect.stack())
```

In terms of the two you've shown, *potentially* the first is faster since you're short circuiting within the loop and don't need to create an entire list, to then iterate over a second time

I say potentially because it would depend on how large the stack is as to how much better off it'd be

Comment: Thank you @Sayse, this code is simplier. One doubt, is this better solution than the one provided by @Chris_Rands in the comments of the question (using `next`)?

Comment: @forvas - I have no idea you'd have to do some performance tests, even if Chris_Rands solution was faster I'd still prefer to use `any` as it is clearer imo what the expected output is

Comment: @forvas `any()` feels a lot cleaner than my suggestion of using `next()`

Comment: I've executed both methods 1.000 times, removed the 50 maximum and 50 minimum execution times, and after that, the sum of all execution times are: **next**: 0.802833080291748, **any**: 0.8027307987213135. Then I executed both 100.000 times and the difference was higher. Seems that `any` is a bit faster than `next`, in addition to be more readable. Thank you both @Sayse and @Chris_Rands.